# При выводе из формы php выводит свой код

Tags: php, html, openserver

Имеется форма авторизации на html, при выводе содержимого `name="email"` и `name="password"`
в php, php выводит свой код. Использую OpenServer

```
                <form method="post" action="index.php" class="form-container">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Ваш Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Пароль</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите пароль">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Отправить</button>
                </form>

               //php в файле index.php

               <?php
               $email = $_POST["email"];
               $password = $_POST["password"];
               echo $email;
               echo $password;
               ?>
```

**Вывод**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего ты неправильно разместил файл на сервере. Попробуй открыть через  OpenServer -> мои сайты.Если не работает покопайся в настройках,может быть где-то лишняя вложенная папка

Comment: Надо открывать файл через `localhost/domain/file.php` или `domain/file.php`, а не напрямую в браузере. Ведь на то openServer и ставится, чтобы открывать с помощью сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно либо создать папку c доменом (например `test.ru`) в папке `domains` и открывать файл в браузере уже с помощью *OS* по адресу `test.ru/FILENAME.php`, либо  создать папку c доменом в папке `domains/localhost` и открывать по адресу `localhost/DOMAIN/FILENAME.php`.

Открывать файлы просто  в браузере через ПКМ  бесполезно, потому что в этом случае сервер не работает. Надо обязательно через домены и непосредственно *OS*

Рекомендую для начала посмотреть информацию по словам "Open Server. Установка и работа с сервером" Видео например